# ASP.NET MVC EF Unable to determine the principal end of association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've encountered some problems with associations while using Entity Framework. Althought there are some other posts about that I couldn't make it working.

```
public class BaseJobOffer : IEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("File")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
}
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public Enums.FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int JobOfferId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseJobOffer JobOffer { get; set; }
}
```

And the error says:
There was an error running selected code generator:

> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for Model.JobOffer'. Unable to determine
>   the principal end of association between the types
>   'Model.BaseJobOffer' and 'Model.File'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Comment: You have the foreign key set on the BaseJobOffer.Id, not on  BaseJobOffer.FileId

Comment: your relational model is unclear : `BaseJobOffer.Id <=> File.Id` one to one relation (this is what you seem to want with PK == FK), so why BaseJobOffer.FileId and why File.JobOfferId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article about ForeignKey attribute usage http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

The `ForeignKey` attribute should be on either the `ForeignKey` property or the `ForeignKeyID` property

```
public class BaseJobOffer : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("File")
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    //or 
    [ForeignKey("FileId")
    public File File { get; set; }
}
```