# How to implement 0..1:0..1 relationship using Data Annotations

Tags: c#

I have two basic classes. I'm trying to add a 1:1 relationship.

what I initially tried

Cashflow.cs

```
public int? Note_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Note_Id")]
public virtual Note Note{ get; set; }
```

Note.cs

```
public int? Cashflow_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Cashflow_Id ")]
public virtual Cashflow Cashflow{ get; set; }
```

The error that is produced initially is

> The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured
>   using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

After googling, from this case [ASP.NET MVC EF Unable to determine the principal end of association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386772/asp-net-mvc-ef-unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-association) I learned that I can add the required data annotations to set which is the principal.

Cashflow.cs

```
[Required]
public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
```

Note.cs

```
public virtual CashFlow CashFlow { get; set; }
```

I was successfully able to add a new migration but the only thing i want to improve on in this approach is to have nullable int columns added as well. May I ask how do i implement a 0..1:0..1 relationship using data annotations that will allow me to have nullable ints on both ends.

Comment: You're not implementing 1:1, you're implementing 0..1:0..1 (it would appear). True 1:1 tends to be *impossible* to implement (and usually points to the two classes probably needing to merge)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for helping point that out =)